# PDF viewer toolbar is disabled in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, microsoft-edge

I am using jquery plugin for opening modal pop-ups. The pop-up can open the pdf document. I am using tag object for displaying pdf like this:

```
<object id="idPdf" width="300" height="400" type="application/pdf"
        data="MY_PDF_URL">
        <span>PDF plugin is not available.</span>
</object>
```

It works fine in all browsers, but the pdf toolbar is missing in MS Edge (user can not save or print). It works fine in new window or tab, but in pop-up has the issue. Anyone know how to fix it?